# Adding or, and in mongodb aggregate $lookup

Tags: database, mongodb, api, mongoose, nestjs

How can i do something like this:

```
        $or: [
          { $and: [{ author: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(author) }, { friend_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(friend_id) }] },
          { $and: [{ author: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(friend_id) }, { friend_id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(author) }] },
        ],
```

In a **aggregate $lookup** function?

Can you help me? Thanks!

**Heres my code**

```
    let rqs:any = this.friendrequestModel.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "author",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "userdata",
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Comment: In `"$lookup"`, drop `"localField"` and `"foreignField"`, and use `"pipeline"`.

Comment: Okay, i have to go, but i will check it out!

Comment: How can i check if theres result from the query?

Comment: Same as always ... look at `"userdata"`.